# ForEach within a function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having trouble getting the desired results using forEach. Assuming that the following code produces the desired results:

```
function isEven(array) {
  var evenNum = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0)
      evenNum.push((array[i]));

  }
  return evenNum;
}

var output = isEven([1, 4, 5, 6, 10, 13]);
console.log(output); // --> [4, 6, 10]

// How do I get the same result with a forEach method?
//  My code reads:

function isEven(array) {
  var evenNum = [];
  array.forEach(function (currentValue) {
    if (currentValue % 2 === 0)
      evenNum.push(array[currentValue]);
  })
  return evenNum;
}

var output = isEven([1, 4, 5, 6, 10, 13]);
console.log(output); // --> [10, 10, 10] not desired
```

Comment: `evenNum.push(currentValue);`

Comment: To use bracket notation use the index of the current iteration withing `.forEach()` callback `array.forEach(function (currentValue, index) {
    if (currentValue % 2 === 0)
      evenNum.push(array[index]);
  })`

Comment: Not to mention you don't get `[10,10,10]` but `[10,undefined,undefined]` because the last two `currentValue` are out of the array bounds.

Comment: Additionally, the array method `filter` might be more suited to this task, eg: `array.filter(function(currentValue) { return currentValue % 2 === 0 })`

Comment: I would write it using es6 as `array.filter(currentValue => currentValue % 2 === 0)`

Comment: Your `isEven()` is breaking conventional naming; one would expect such a function name to return a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var even;
```

For loop:

```
even = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i)
    if (numbers[i] % 2 === 0)
        even.push(numbers[i]);
console.log(even);
```

Using forEach:

```
even = [];
numbers.forEach(n => {
    if (n % 2 === 0)
        even.push(n);
});
console.log(even);
```

Or more succinctly:

```
even = numbers.filter(n => (n % 2 === 0));
console.log(even);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are indexing into the array when you should use the `currentValue` directly.

```
function isEven(array){
    var evenNum = [];
    array.forEach(function(currentValue){
        if(currentValue % 2 === 0)
        evenNum.push(currentValue);
    })
    return evenNum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `evenNum.push(array[currentValue])`. It should be `evenNum.push(currentValue)`.

```js
function isEven(array) {
  var evenNum = [];
  array.forEach(function (currentValue) {
    if (currentValue % 2 === 0)
      evenNum.push(currentValue);
  })
  return evenNum;
}

var output = isEven([1, 4, 5, 6, 10, 13]);
console.log(output); // --> [10, 10, 10] not desired
```